# How to display one of Drupal's default forms

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have a module that I want to use to display a modified version of one of Drupal 7's default forms. I believe the form ID is `user_profile_form` and it is the form used to edit a user's account information.

So this is the structure of my module:

1. hook_menu with a page callback to a function --> `user_exe_edit()` -->
2. function `user_exe_edit()` calls `drupal_get_form(input_simple_form)` -->
3. function `input_simple_form($form, &$form_submit)`

Now I need the function `input_simple_form` to return the Drupal form with id `user_profile_form`.

How do I do that?

Comment: Hi Charlie! You really should post drupal questions in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ , you will probably get more answers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't need your input_simple_form(), but you will need to include the user module's pages:

```
global $user;
// if the user is logged in, otherwise anonymous users will see it
if ($user->uid > 0) {
   module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
   return user_edit($user);
}
```